# href beautifulsoul html selection doesn't return wanted result

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, css-selectors

I want to extract all the first href of the first  link by beautiful soup
as shown my code HTML

```
<body> 
    <div>
        some html
        <footer>
            <div>...</div>
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <a href="some link alpha"></a>      #<<<<<<------- i want this
                <a href="some link beta"></a>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            some html
            <footer>
                <div>...</div>
                <div>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <a href="somelink gamma"></a>  #<<<<<<------- i want this too
                    <a href="somelink delta"></a>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
....
    </body>
```

i want to return an array of the wanted links, in this case it's [alpha,gamma]

here is my python code:

```
html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
content = soup.find_all('footer div a',attrs={'href' : True})

for a in content:
    print ("Found the URL:", a['href'])
```

the code is not giving what i want, if i make only 'a' it returns all the links, i tried many things but no given results, even css selector didn't work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

sample_html = """
    <div>
        some html
        <footer>
            <div>...</div>
            <div>
                <span></span>
                <span></span>
                <a href="link1 i want"></a>      #<<<<<<------- i want this
                <a href="unwanted link1"></a>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
    
        <div>
            some html
            <footer>
                <div>...</div>
                <div>
                    <span></span>
                    <span></span>
                    <a href="link2 i want"></a>  #<<<<<<------- i want this too
                    <a href="unwanted link2"></a>
                </div>
            </footer>
        </div>
"""

links_you_want = [
    footer.find("a")["href"] for footer in 
    BeautifulSoup(sample_html, "html.parser").find_all("footer")
]

print(links_you_want)
```

Output:

```
 ['link1 i want', 'link2 i want']
```

Comment: but i can't make difference between text [it can be similar] , i just want to get the first a without conditonal text, but conditions based on position

Comment: Well then, based on your HTML sample that's the best you can get. Edit the question with a sample that closer to your actual HTML or share a URL.

Comment: it's clear that href is just a random value that i ignore so i can't make condition on it, the goal is to return the first href of each footer element

Comment: Alright, I get it. See the updated answer.